# How to apply @mock.patch for method and keep access to original method within one or more Tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

While working on unittests for python application I faced interesting case when `mock.patch` activate mocking via `start()` method. To reproduce problem put code below into two files `tests.py` and `utils.py` and place them under one folder:

tests.py:

```
import mock
import unittest

import utils


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_method_a(self):
        mock.patch('utils.method_b', return_value=None).start()
        actual_result = utils.method_a()
        # Assertion code

    def test_method_b(self):
        actual_result = utils.method_b()
        self.assertTrue(actual_result is None)
```

utils.py:

```
def method_a():
    print 'A Method'
    return method_b()

def method_b():
    print 'B Method'
    return True
```

Pay attention that `test_method_a` mocking `app_utils.method_b` and `test_method_b` are going to call original `app_utils.method_b`. I faced situation that `test_method_b` cannot call actual `app_utils.method_b` because it's mocked by `test_method_a`.

I knew few methods of how to resolve that problem:

- use `from app.utils import test_method_b`, - so method would leave in namespace of my test.py
- use `mock.patch` as context manager via `with` statement.
- use `mock.patch` as decorator.

The question is whether that possible to resolve problem without applying solutions above?

I need to keep using `mock.patch` and `imports` as is, if possible.

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? The `patch`ing should end after the first test method does. Have you considered splitting it into separate test classes?

Comment: Actually i've noticed that problem when executed few test classes at once, some of them mocking method and some of them not, so i cannot test that method because it's mocked in other test methods

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] including code under test to allow others to recreate this?

Comment: After more detailed investigation of problem reason i have updated questions.@jonrsharpe Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Firstly, you should test for `None` by identity, not equality; `assert something is None`. Secondly, why do you `start` but not `stop` your patch? Thirdly, why not use the decorator form that the original question claimed you were set on?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, that method mocked via decorator and via start method, eventually i thought that issue triggered by decorator, but it was triggered by not using `stop` method as i understood now, so thank you very match for your time.

Comment: I am curious and waitiing for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The weird behaviour described above occurred due to not stopping of patcher which mock method_b.**

See working code below:

`utils.py` file is the same as in question.

`tests.py`:

```
import mock
import unittest

import utils


class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_method_a(self):
        method_b_patcher = mock.patch('utils.method_b', return_value=None)
        method_b_patcher.start()
        actual_result = utils.method_a()
        method_b_patcher.stop()

    def test_method_b(self):
        actual_result = utils.method_b()
        self.assertTrue(actual_result)
```

So what is updated is that in `test_method_a` i've added `method_b_patcher` and call `start` and `stop` for that patcher within `test_method_a` method.

Comment: I see - it is useful when test_method_a() requires to run utils.method_b() first.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right,  i have just wanted to point problem on mocking flow, so i have didn't pay attention to that moment...know i've updated Q.